# Could not recognize the tag for the optimization of the audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I've pubblished my rss feed for facebbok instant articles. 
When I test my url in *Instant-Article* --> *Configuration* --> *debug feed rss* I see for any article the following warning message "**Could not recognize the tag for the optimization of the audience. Update the item with new tags and try again**".
I'm using Facebook audience network, with one active position.

I've set 
`<meta property="fb:use_automatic_ad_placement" content="true">`

and

```
<figure class="op-ad"><iframe width="320" height="50" style="border:0; margin:0;" src="https://www.facebook.com/adnw_request?placement={my_id}&amp;adtype={type}"></iframe>
</figure>
```

for every article.
In the official documentation I didn't find nothing of relevant about this message.
Can someone say me where I'm wrong?

Comment: That message doesn't seem to make sense - for the optimization of the public what? Are you sure it's the full message, and it's coming from Facebook?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm sorry I'm translating it from italian, the original message is 'Impossibile riconoscere i tag per l'ottimizzazione del pubblico', I've edited the title, maybe now is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [Facebook Instant Article documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/article):
I was passing the `op:tags` meta empty in this way:

```
<meta property="op:tags" content='@Model.GetTags()'>
```

but `Model.GetTags()` was giving me empty string, after the change in this method the error disappeared immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Is {my_id} and {type} being replaced with the proper values? {my_id} should align with your Audience Network app ID and placement ID and the type should be "banner320x50".

Comment: Yes, they are replaced by real values